# how to select echo option value and java script?

Tags: javascript, php

I need Option value from this query "echo Option Value and JSArray".

this option value :

```
echo '<option value="'. $li['nama_emp'] .'">'. $li['nama_emp'].'</option>';
```

this Option Value JS :

```
$jsArray .= "prdName['" . $li['nama_emp'] . "'] = {akses:'" . addslashes($li['hak_akses']) . "'};\n";
```

thanks for help

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3">Asisten Manager/Manager</label> 
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="mng" id="mng" class="form-control"  onchange='changeValue(this.value)' required>
        ?php
            $sql_don = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE hak_akses in ('Manager','Asisten Manager')
             and divisi='$divisi'AND active='Aktif' ORDER BY nama_emp ASC";
                $ress_don = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_don);
                $jsArray = "var prdName = new Array();\n";
                while($li = mysqli_fetch_array($ress_don)) {
                echo '<option value="'. $li['nama_emp'] .'">'. $li['nama_emp'].'</option>';
                $jsArray .= "prdName['" . $li['nama_emp'] . "'] = {akses:'" . addslashes($li['hak_akses']) . "'};\n";                   
            }
        ?>
</select>

        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Jabatan </label> 
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    
                    <input class="form-control"  name="akses" id="akses" readonly />      
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP snippet

```
$sql_don = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE hak_akses in ('Manager','Asisten Manager') and divisi='$divisi'AND active='Aktif' ORDER BY nama_emp ASC";
$ress_don = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_don);
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($ress_don, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Javascript snippet inside php file

```
let employee = <?= json_encode($result) ?>;
```

Now you have your query results as an array of objects which can be used in your javascript